# React Three loading multiple textures to same 3d model

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a component as follows:

```
function Character(props) {
    const obj = useFBX('/character.fbx');

    const bodyNormal = useTexture('/textures/body_normal.png')
    const bodyColor = useTexture('/textures/body_base_color.png')

    return <mesh>
        <primitive object={obj} />
        <meshBasicMaterial map={bodyNormal} attach="material-0" />
        <meshBasicMaterial map={bodyColor} attach="material-1" />
    </mesh>
}
```

I can see that the model is loaded correctly however the textures are not being loaded, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshBasicMaterial` cannot take in a normal map (it is unlit, so it uses no lighting calculations at all) - using a material like `MeshStandardMaterial` will work with multiple imported maps, you just apply them all to the material.

See https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial for all possible map types.

```
function Character(props) {
    const obj = useFBX('/character.fbx');

    const bodyNormal = useTexture('/textures/body_normal.png')
    const bodyColor = useTexture('/textures/body_base_color.png')

    return <mesh>
        <primitive object={obj} />
        <meshStandardMaterial map={bodyColor} normalMap={bodyNormal} />
    </mesh>
}
```

Assuming you are using `useTexture` from Drei (https://github.com/pmndrs/drei), you can shorten that up:

```
const [bodyColor, bodyNormal] = useTexture([
  '/textures/body_base_color.png', 
  '/textures/body_normal.png',
])
```

or

```
const props = useTexture({
  map: '/textures/body_base_color.png', 
  normalMap: '/textures/body_normal.png',
})
// <meshStandardMaterial {...props} />
```